# Java: Why doesn't my KeyEvent work?

Tags: java, keyboard

Hey so I'm fairly new to java, but based on doing a lot of research and analyzing various code, I came up with some code to move a basic circle on a screen by using arrow keys.

However, for some reason, the code does not run the whole key event.  If I press any key on the **keyboard**, even different **arrow keys**, it will cause the circle to only move one direction.

Based on my code, I feel like everything should work, but it just won't run the `KeyEvent` function properly.  Any ways to fix it?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class second extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{
  Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
  int x = 0, y = 0, velx = 0, vely = 0;

  public second()
  {
    t.start();
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 40, 40));
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    x += velx;
    y += vely;
    repaint();
  }

  public void up()
  {
    velx = 0;
    vely = 2;
  }

  public void down()
  {
    velx = 0;
    vely = -2;
  }
  public void left()
  {
    velx = -2;
    vely = 0;
  }
  public void right()
  {
    velx = 2;
    vely = 0;
  }

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
  {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP);
    {
      up();
    }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    {
      down();
    }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
    {
      left();
    }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    {
      right();
    }
  }

  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
  {
  }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
  {
    velx = 0;
    vely = 0;
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    second s = new second();
    f.add(s);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(800, 600);
  }
}
```

Comment: your `keyPressed` events is not registered with any components of `Swing`. @Alan. Its must to bind the event with the component on which you want to invoke this `keyPressed` Event.

Comment: A little hint on figuring out what makes your code act as it does, is to use the debugger. In this case it is super simple to use the debugger. Or even more crude, use prints.

Comment: Hi. If you feel the solution provided by me is right, please mark it complete. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, ActionListener is not required in this case. KeyListener is sufficient. Also there is a semicolon beside if statements, this is causing all the functions up, down, left and right to be invoked negating the effect.

Also for up, y should be reduced and for down, y should be increased.

Please find the below code which works fine. You can limit the right and down movement with MAX_LIMIT based on the window size. I limited it for 0,0 for left and up movement.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Second extends JPanel implements KeyListener
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
  public Second()
  {
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 40, 40));
  }

  public void up()
  {
    if(y >= 5) {
        y -= 5;
        repaint();  
    }    
  }

  public void down()
  { 
    y += 5;
    repaint();
  }

  public void left()
  {   
    if(x >= 5) {
        x -= 5;
        repaint();  
    }
  }

  public void right()
  {   
    x += 5;
    repaint();  
  }

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
  {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
      up();
    }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
      down();
    }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
      left();
    }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
      right();
    }
  }

  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
  {
  }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
  {
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Second s = new Second();
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.add(s);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(800, 600);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have a semi-colon following your first if statement in keyPressed(), which impeaches considering following instructions. cf :

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        up();
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        down();
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        left();
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        right();
}
```

You also have a negative value for vely in down() where it should be positive (and vice-versa). And since you already reset velx and vely to 0 on keyReleased(), it is unnecessary to do it in your directions functions.

```
public void up() {
    vely = -2;
}

public void down() {
    vely = 2;
}
```

Class names should be CamelCase (not lowercase as presented).

Have fun.